# getting the url of opened link uiwebview

Tags: iphone, xcode

so user touches link in uiwebview, the page opens.. how do I get the new url so I can show it in a uilabel? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: in your UIWebViewDelegate.  In there you can get the [request.URL absoluteString] to show in your UILabel.